# SQL Injection Attack logged

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

A Hacker attempted to inject the following in every text field:
`!S!WCRTESTINPUT000006!E!`

inside a database.

the DB is a MySQL db and it got logged (inserted) over and over.

What is the meaning of that particular character in an attempt to SQL inject into a mysql databse?

I couldn't find a match on stackoverlow of someone who has asked this before

Comment: this was most likely an automated vulnerability probe, you need to fix the vulnerability that caused it asap

Comment: Looking around I found out that this has come from something called WebCruiser which scans for vulnerabilities with a sql injection proof of concept test. Basically this entry was a proof of concept so you need to fix this flaw before they do something about it

Comment: Its WebCruiser tool which do sql inject http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/4015/t1594641-tool-produces-this-input-wcrtestinput000000/